# Maven Dependency Plugin and Classifiers

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-dependency-plugin

I am having an issue with the maven dependency plugin using *dependency-get*. The item that I am trying to download from the Maven repository has a number of different artifact types:

- POM File
- JAR File
- RPM Package

When executing the following command, I successfully get the latest snapshot of pom file (and this works similarly for the JAR file).

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get -Drepourl=<My Nexus Server> -DgroupId=<group> -DartifactId=<artifact> -Dpackaging=pom -Dversion=latest
```

However, when I use the following, it seems to completely skip the latest version resolution and attempt to download a version named "latest" of the RPM (and fail).

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get -Drepourl=<My Nexus Server> -DgroupId=<group> -DartifactId=<artifact> -Dpackaging=rpm -Dversion=latest -Dclassifier=rpm
```

The difference here seems to be that the RPM has a classifier (rpm) that the other items do not.

I am using an internal Nexus server to host the packages.

Comment: I would assume that the rpm does not has the packaging `pom` i would assume it has the packaging `rpm` instead.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my question there, using packaging=rpm